# How to find the nearest decimal value

Tags: sql, sqlite, spatial

Am developing MAP app. It saves several thousands for latitude & longitude details to draw overlay. 
When user touches the overlay it wants to fetch the nearest latitude and longitude from the saved record in SQL.

I use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM track_points 
WHERE segmentId = '22' 
ORDER BY (ABS(latitude - 25.312005) + ABS(longitude - 91.730433))
```

It exactly does the same but the problem is when the particular overlay has several thousands of lat and longi details. **It takes a long time to complete the above query.**

It runs thought the entire DB data to get one point, even when the nearest data is fetched.

Just **when 28.2525 is given I need something near 25.2520** or what ever it is and stop with that. I don't want to start from 22.23252 or something in row 10 and reach 25.2520 at row 5000 and yet conti till the last row.

Comment: I would suggest you to use [Spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) which is a GIS extension of Sqlite and tailor made for kind of work you are doing. You can get significant increase in performance if you utilize Spatial indexing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me make take a look at Spatialite and get back to you. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, continue to investigate if Spatialite is what you need.

However, you need to cut down the number of points that the query is considering:

```
SELECT * 
FROM track_points 
WHERE segmentId = '22' 
ORDER BY (ABS(latitude - 25.312005) + ABS(longitude - 91.730433))
WHERE latitude BETWEEN 25.31 AND 25.32
      AND
      longitude BETWEEN 91.73 AND 91.74
```

You want to set the boundaries as narrow as possible but wide enough to be sure you get at least one result. If your lattitude and longitude are a regular lattice then this is trivial.

You can use `BETWEEN @value - @tolerance AND @value + @tolerance` to detrimine the values on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It really reduced numbers rows to be executed very effectively to 98% in all cases. But the thing right now is, still sqlite takes 2sec to execute the statement on device. Previously it executed 7000 plus rows and now just 5 - 40 rows max. yet why sqlite takes 2 secs as before to execute the statement.

Comment: SELECT * FROM track_points 
WHERE segmentId = '27' 
AND latitude BETWEEN 25.592121 AND 25.594120 
AND longitude BETWEEN 91.871140 AND 91.873138
ORDER BY (ABS(latitude - 25.593121) + ABS(longitude - 91.872141)); This is my current optimized statement after your advice

Comment: Do you have an index on each of lat and long?

Comment: Thats what I didn't do, to reduce DB size from increasing. I just did that and now query executes very fast. Thanks for your very useful help. Thank you so much Dale

Comment: Hard disc space is cheap - time is expensive! Economise the right one.